# Reading and writing Audio File services for single audio file to sync with its contents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, core-audio

How i can use Audio file services to read and write single audio file to sync with its contents.Have a single audio file to play and displaying its contents in textview programmatically but there is no synchronization when audio plays and when contents display in text view.

Is there any example or sample code for this.

Appreciate help.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to display in the text view?

Comment: Textview is showing text which is actually audio file contents but there is no synchronization between audiofile and textview text. Based on nstimer displaying audiofile contents in textview.

Comment: I guess I'm puzzled about the purpose of displaying a file's contents in a text view.  What do you mean by synchronizing the view and the file- something like a lyrics display?

Comment: playing an audio file and then display content triggered by a timer. Maintaining an NSTimer on a separate thread not working reliably. Track is of 5.26 minutes. Researched and found that synchronizing with callbacks from AudioUnit. An AudioUnit has a callback property can be set and then pass in an AURenderCallbackStruct. That callback will have a timestamp. do you know of a working example that plays a file using a callback